# Contact Form AJAX not working in Craft 3

Tags: craft3, ajax, plugin-contactform

This is my first Craft website, and after trying out Craft 2 I decided it would be a good idea to have move my site to Craft 3 for longevity.

I used to the free Contact Form plugin and managed to make AJAX work perfectly with Craft 2.

However the same code does not work with Craft 3.

I have a simple contact form at the bottom of https://haydentomas.co.uk where the AJAX works perfectly.

I used exactly the same code on a Craft 3 install at https://letsdocode.com. The error messages come up correctly if you don't fill in the form properly, and I do get an email if it does get filled in. But I cannot make the form success message appear when it has been completed successfully.

On the JS I have an success:

```
function(response) {
    if (response.success) {
```

Statement that holds some HTML that appears on an id and also another statement that hides the form completely.

This does not work and I am wondering if there is a change in Craft 3 that means I have to change the code slightly?

My else statement works perfectly.

My JS is below

```
   <script>
    $('form').submit(function(ev) {
      // Prevent the form from actually submitting
      ev.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
      // Send it to the server
      $.ajax('/', {    
        url:  '/',
        data: formData,
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
          document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML = '<h2>Success!</h2><div class="row"><div class="6u"><img class="monkey" src="https://haydentomas.co.uk//images/monkey.svg"/> </div><div class="6u"><p>Thank you for your message</p><p>I will get back to you as soon as possible, usually within 24 hours</p><p>Talk soon! Hayden</p></div></div>';
          // $('form')[0].reset();
          document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            // response.error will be an object containing any validation errors that occurred, indexed by field name
            // e.g. response.error.fromName => ['From Name is required']
            document.getElementsByName('fromName')[0].placeholder='Name is required';
            document.getElementsByName('fromEmail')[0].placeholder='Email is required';
            document.getElementsByName('message')[0].placeholder='Message is required';
            }
          }
          });
      });
</script>
```

My form is

```
<div id="form">
    <form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN" value="p_O1wR-QVP9G9WpcPZ90Fl4K82X8kOvZ33FAXa7fej9HSTOMW4zC_GWWsVDAVlvkr_TjeheMVdsk15JD5C8D-CSrFP0Ehb9kCoyHF42u_37Myy_akFOwXWJprfT4KWOqpzUhWd6r0ib9QLr7G2cDBUtxDH9JgIF3alyLyHuZhZXAO_eR79zoCVniIzlieZZi0FOsLQhYQxSpOVuzLDdFAg7P2U7zQBUXSJ1dnNXapMuyTUjLcuu3sJNFLzwozOcOGqo1K9kGRSTxXU2_bF4FctCHwoxe-gXSCLBcBRDzN1s9S7c9yNWZ6etHMC_7qxNXf31luALE9sgZ9dcy92c6gJaS2xggume9EOKnd4dLNMkRmiTEZeaIXTLvsXG5yplOqvNJ6aVhhW5XXpmRzh1ayJNXFGm7zuRHxDfOjFYmaVRmP0lJEK3tNCc_yowjrcDn8A_B4Z2JnGAx2hdvViDeVuQvnVEsajowmAp__gJ_FlRrm7gPlCRyYTzJLtSTls2fnDkCoB7b-9v6FURVfpmjRSyZfGqWVgRDpBV0xVo9dRc=">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact-form/send">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="b72e5e9e85a0ff7d840441aa540d6d32c6d554d22c025c8fc4dc8e0804c9475fcontact/thanks">

        <h3><label for="from-name">Your Name</label></h3>
        <input id="from-name" type="text" name="fromName" value="">

        <h3><label for="from-email">Your Email</label></h3>
        <input id="from-email" type="email" name="fromEmail" value="">

        <h3><label for="subject">Subject</label></h3>
        <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" value="">

        <h3><label for="message">Message</label></h3>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="message" name="message"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need your html in order to help you. Your Javascript seems to be "correct". I know one could inspect  it on your website but people on smartphones might help you too when you post it

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have added the form to the post. I am pretty sure the form should work, as it does on craft2, so must be a different success message, or I have missed something!

Comment: As far as I can see you don't close your `</form>` and there is no `div` with id `notice` the response message from the controller still contains an attribute `success`. You can do `console.log(response)` to see what you get

Answer (score 1):

Contact Form 2 (for Craft 3), still returns a JSON encoded `success: true` response on successful submission, but Craft 3 by default will only respond with JSON if `$request->getAcceptsJson()` returns `true` on a request.

https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form/blob/v2/src/controllers/SendController.php#L64-L66

Ultimately that ends up hitting the Yii 2 method [getAcceptableContentTypes](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#getAcceptableContentTypes()-detail) which checks the `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']` server variable for the key `application/json`.

So most likely your server is not configured to return `application/json` as a valid `HTTP_ACCEPT` content-type.